# Cargo not installed error when installing lckr-jupyterlab-variableinspector

Tags: variables, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, inspector

I used `pip install lckr-jupyterlab-variableinspector` to install this [variable inspector for jupyterlab](https://github.com/lckr/jupyterlab-variableInspector). I got this error

```
Collecting lckr-jupyterlab-variableinspector
  Using cached lckr_jupyterlab_variableinspector-3.0.9.tar.gz (60 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [161 lines of output]
      Collecting jupyter_packaging~=0.7.9
        Using cached jupyter_packaging-0.7.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
      Collecting jupyterlab==3.*,>=3.0.0rc13
        Using cached jupyterlab-3.6.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl (8.9 MB)
      Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
        Using cached setuptools-66.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting ipython
        Using cached ipython-8.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (775 kB)
      Collecting jupyterlab-server~=2.10
        Using cached jupyterlab_server-2.19.0-py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
      Collecting tornado>=6.1.0
        Using cached tornado-6.2-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (419 kB)
      Collecting jupyter-server-ydoc<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
        Using cached jupyter_server_ydoc-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
      Collecting jupyter-core
        Using cached jupyter_core-5.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
      Collecting notebook<7
        Using cached notebook-6.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (439 kB)
      Collecting jupyter-server<3,>=1.16.0
        Using cached jupyter_server-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (365 kB)
      Collecting packaging
        Using cached packaging-23.0-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
      Collecting jinja2>=2.1
        Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
      Collecting nbclassic
        Using cached nbclassic-0.4.8-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 MB)
      Collecting tomli
        Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
      Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
        Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.2-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (13 kB)
      Collecting websocket-client
        Using cached websocket_client-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
      Collecting nbformat>=5.3.0
        Using cached nbformat-5.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
      Collecting prometheus-client
        Using cached prometheus_client-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
      Collecting terminado>=0.8.3
        Using cached terminado-0.17.1-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
      Collecting jupyter-client>=7.4.4
        Using cached jupyter_client-7.4.9-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
      Collecting send2trash
        Using cached Send2Trash-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
      Collecting pyzmq>=24
        Using cached pyzmq-25.0.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_15_universal2.whl (1.8 MB)
      Collecting anyio<4,>=3.1.0
        Using cached anyio-3.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (80 kB)
      Collecting argon2-cffi
        Using cached argon2_cffi-21.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
      Collecting traitlets>=5.6.0
        Using cached traitlets-5.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (116 kB)
      Collecting jupyter-events>=0.4.0
        Using cached jupyter_events-0.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
      Collecting nbconvert>=6.4.4
        Using cached nbconvert-7.2.8-py3-none-any.whl (274 kB)
      Collecting jupyter-server-terminals
        Using cached jupyter_server_terminals-0.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
      Collecting platformdirs>=2.5
        Using cached platformdirs-2.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
      Collecting jupyter-server-fileid<1,>=0.6.0
        Using cached jupyter_server_fileid-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
      Collecting jupyter-ydoc<0.4.0,>=0.2.0
        Using cached jupyter_ydoc-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
      Collecting ypy-websocket<0.9.0,>=0.8.2
        Using cached ypy_websocket-0.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
      Collecting json5>=0.9.0
        Using cached json5-0.9.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
      Collecting requests>=2.28
        Using cached requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
      Collecting jsonschema>=4.17.3
        Using cached jsonschema-4.17.3-py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
      Collecting babel>=2.10
        Using cached Babel-2.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 MB)
      Collecting importlib-metadata>=4.8.3
        Using cached importlib_metadata-6.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
      Collecting ipython-genutils
        Using cached ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
      Collecting ipykernel
        Using cached ipykernel-6.20.2-py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
      Collecting nest-asyncio>=1.5
        Using cached nest_asyncio-1.5.6-py3-none-any.whl (5.2 kB)
      Collecting notebook-shim>=0.1.0
        Using cached notebook_shim-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
      Collecting stack-data
        Using cached stack_data-0.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
      Collecting backcall
        Using cached backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
      Collecting appnope
        Using cached appnope-0.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.4 kB)
      Collecting decorator
        Using cached decorator-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
      Collecting pexpect>4.3
        Using cached pexpect-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
      Collecting prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>=3.0.11
        Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.36-py3-none-any.whl (386 kB)
      Collecting pickleshare
        Using cached pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
      Collecting pygments>=2.4.0
        Using cached Pygments-2.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting matplotlib-inline
        Using cached matplotlib_inline-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (9.4 kB)
      Collecting jedi>=0.16
        Using cached jedi-0.18.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
      Collecting sniffio>=1.1
        Using cached sniffio-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
      Collecting idna>=2.8
        Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
      Collecting pytz>=2015.7
        Using cached pytz-2022.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (499 kB)
      Collecting zipp>=0.5
        Using cached zipp-3.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
      Collecting parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0
        Using cached parso-0.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
      Collecting attrs>=17.4.0
        Using cached attrs-22.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
      Collecting pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0
        Using cached pyrsistent-0.19.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (82 kB)
      Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.2
        Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
      Collecting entrypoints
        Using cached entrypoints-0.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
      Collecting pyyaml>=5.3
        Using cached PyYAML-6.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (197 kB)
      Collecting python-json-logger>=2.0.4
        Using cached python_json_logger-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 kB)
      Collecting rfc3986-validator>=0.1.1
        Using cached rfc3986_validator-0.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
      Collecting rfc3339-validator
        Using cached rfc3339_validator-0.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5 kB)
      Collecting jupyter-events>=0.4.0
        Using cached jupyter_events-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
      Collecting y-py<0.6.0,>=0.5.3
        Using cached y_py-0.5.5.tar.gz (50 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [6 lines of output]

            Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
            This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
            the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

            Checking for Rust toolchain....
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

      × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
      ╰─> See above for output.

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]
```

Then, I installed rust via `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`, but it showed the same error.

Then, I tried to add `export PATH = "$PATH:/Users/username/.cargo/bin"` to `.bash_profile`  but again it showed the same error.

I've seen people's discussion of similar issue [here](https://github.com/ijl/orjson/issues/192). I have pip-22.3.1 but I'm not too sure about the version of python.

I don't know if it's related but I'm using macOS with M1 chip.